# Color according to value in stack barplot R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am building a stacked bar plot using the following code

```
test <- as.matrix(read.csv(file="test4.csv",sep=",",head=TRUE))
test <- test[,2:ncol(test)]
pdf(file="test.pdf", height=15, width=20)
par(lwd = 0.3)
xLabLocs <- barplot(test, space=0.4, xaxt='n', yaxt='n', col=heat.colors(13))
axis(1, cex.axis=0.5, las=2, at=xLabLocs, labels=colnames(test))
axis(2, cex.axis=0.5, pos=-0.5)
dev.off()
```

And I would like the colors of each section to be proportional to its height. For example, if each stack is made up of X number of sections, the section with the longest height would be at one end of the "spectrum"(ie really bright blue), and the shortest height section would be at the other end of the "spectrum"(ie really dim blue).

This is what I get instead:
[image]

In this case what I get is sections at the bottom at one end of the spectrum and the sections at the top at the other end of the spectrum. 
Thanks

This is some sample data

```
BARCODES,   BC1_AATCAGGC,   BC10_ACAAGGCT,  BC11_ACACGATC,  BC12_ACACTGAC
1,  2432,   420,    18, 69
2,  276,    405,    56, 86
3,  119,    189,    110,    51
4,  90, 163,    140,    68
5,  206,    280,    200,    122
6,  1389,   1080,   1075,   614
7,  3983,   3258,   4878,   2994
8,  7123,   15828,  28111,  7892
9,  8608,   48721,  52576,  21220
10, 9639,   44725,  55951,  18284
11, 8323,   45695,  32166,  7747
12, 2496,   18254,  26600,  5134
13, 1524,   8591,   18583,  3705
```

Comment: You need to provide more information to get an answer to this one.  When you say you want the colour to vary with section height do you want that to be a linear relationship or do you want it to be categorical within a bar such that the longest section in a bar is always the same colour regardless of how long it is?  A small sample of the data making a completely reproducible chart would go a long way here.

Comment: Thanks @John, I would like it to be a linear relationship.

Comment: There's probably an elegant ggplot2 way to do this, I'll add a tag to draw some of that crowd's attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`barp` from the `plotrix` package allows you to pass in a matrix of colours to use for each group and bar so you could specify them like that, except that `barp` doesn't do stacked barplots (i.e. it can only do `barplot(...,beside=TRUE)` not  `barplot(...,beside=FALSE)`).

Alternatively, you can use `rect` to individually draw each rectangle of the bar chart with the specified colour (!).

Here's the function I devised (modify as you need it of course):

```
% mybarplot( x, col=heat.colors(255), space=0.2, labels=NULL )
% makes a stacked bar plot with ncol(x) bars, each containing nrow(x)
%  stacks. Coloured according to a *global* colour scale (by value of top edge
%  of the box within the stack). This is as opposed to the same colour 
%  per category across all bars.
%
% PARAMETERS
% ----------
% x     : a matrix. COLUMNS are the categories, ROWS contain the data.
% col   : colour scheme to use. e.g. heat.colors, rainbow, ...
% space : space between bars as a fraction of bar width.
% labels: labels for each category (column) of x, default colnames(x)
%
% EXAMPLE
% -------
% bar plot with 3 categories/bars, 4 stacks in each bar.
% data <- matrix(runif(12),ncol=3,nrow=4)
% colnames(data)<-c('group a','group b','group c')
% mybarplot(data,col=heat.colors(20))
%
mybarplot <- function( x, col=heat.colors(255), space=0.2, labels=colnames(x) )
{
 maxy <- max(x)
 miny <- 0
 n    <- ncol(x)
 m    <- nrow(x)
 wid  <- 1

 # work out boundaries of each rectangle
 # note: sort the y's ascending to draw properly.
 xsort  <- apply(x,2,sort)
 xright <- rep(1:n, m) * (wid+space) - space
 ybottom <- as.vector(t(rbind(miny,xsort)))

 # work out colour of each rectangle,
 # being (y/maxy) along the colour scale.
 fracs<-as.vector(t(xsort))/maxy
 cols <- col[round(fracs*(length(col)-1))+1]

 # plot: set up grid and then draw rectangles
 plot(0, 0, type="n", 
      ylim=c(miny,maxy), xlim=c(0,max(xright)),
      xaxt='n',yaxt='n',xlab=NA,ylab=NA)
 rect(xright-wid, ybottom[1:(length(ybottom)-n)], xright, ybottom[-(1:n)],
      col=cols)

 # draw labels
 axis(1, cex.axis=0.5, las=2, at=xright[1:n]-(space+wid)/2, labels=labels)
 axis(2, cex.axis=0.5, pos=-0.5)
}
```

Example output from your test data with `mybarplot(test)`:
[image: stacked bar graph with global colour scale]

See how the colour of the boxes depends on how high up they reach. It's the top of the box that determines the colour, not the bottom. If you wanted to use (say) the bottom of the box to determine colour instead, modify the `fracs` line accordingly.

Note, I'd fiddle with it to at least modify your `axis` commands because they're really small and hard to read!

Perhaps omit them from the function but return `xright[1:n]-(space+wid)/2` from `mybarplot` and use as in `xLabLocs <- mybarplot(test)`, allowing you to fiddle with extra graphics commands like `axis` outside of the function.

Comment: note - would still love to see a `ggplot` solution if anyone has one!